# Why can't I use certain free FontAwesome icons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

I'm working on a React App that uses [Font-awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react). I'm able to get icons like the comment bubble working fine with `import { faComment } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'`. But there are certain icons such as [the search icon](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/search?style=solid) that don't seem to be importable, despite being free. Does anyone know why there is this discrepancy between icons? What should I do in order to import the search icon? We are already using the `<FontAwesomeIcon />` component syntax across the app so I would prefer to avoid `<i class="fas fa-search"></i>` if possible.

Comment: _"don't seem to be importable"_... what does this mean? What happens when you try? Do you get any errors?

Comment: No, there's no result for anything resembling a search icon. The project is already using 3 different font-awesome packages so I thought maybe there is a fourth that contains the other icons? I don't think so though.

Comment: [`faSearch`](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/js-packages/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faSearch.js) is part of the `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
import React from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be under solid, so fas, i.e fasSearch. I don't have it in front of me though